# Are Domain Hacks usable?

Tags: urls, branding

A [Domain Hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_hack) is when the top level domain (ux.stackexchange.**com**) and sometimes the subdomain (**ux**.stackexchange.com) is used to spell out a word instead of being used as a country code (.us, .uk) or organization type indicator (.com, .gov). This results in site names like "del.icio.us".

The resulting names are cute, but are they usable? I can't imagine telling my mother "Okay, just navigate to 'd-e-l-dot-i-c-i-o-dot-us'...". Comunicating such URLs in spoken conversation is awkward at best. If your only interaction with the URL is inside a browser it's largely irrelevant, but still the name might not *look* like a URL without the familiar .com/etc. top level domain.

Is there data or any good articles covering this issue?

Comment: Great observation, I have wondered this myself.

Comment: I'm curious on any articles, data on this as well.  Personal experience is that it depends on domain.  Del.icio.us - no.  Something like Craft.ly - yes since it is easy to remember and it's broken at a natural English word suffix.  Again, curious to see if there are any articles on such though.

Comment: The addition of the subdomain hack makes del.icio.us particularly awkward IMO, but top level domain hacks bug me too. I additionally have a problem with them using country/ect domains to make a "cute" URL instead of their intended purpose, but that's a moral and SEO issue not as much UX.

Comment: I've always pushed for buying the dot-com version in addition to the "cute" URL... and not considering a URL is the .com version isn't available. Just like Bitly owns bit.ly and bitly.com.

Comment: @DanielNewman very good idea. Bit.ly makes sense as a url shortener, there the domain hack is used to keep a short URL. I hate url shorteners too, especially since Twitter auto shortens URLs now, but oh well.

Comment: There's also the problem of not remembering whether it's `del.icio.us` or `de.licio.us` or `deli.cio.us`.

Comment: Sometimes those cute URLs are also the result of not owning the proper one.

Comment: @kontur I think that's *usually* the case. On the other hand, I had thought Apple's mobile.me service was at mobile.me, but it was me.com (:

Answer (score 5):

I think I tread the line between Ben and Daniel. I think that, if the domain is to be considered professional, then going with both the .com and the domain hack would be fine in my opinion.  However, I can only go with that as long as the brand didn't rely on the "cute" domain.

There's something to be said about the "web-savvy" vs the "not-so-web-savvy" here.  For bit.ly, it's fine to push that domain hack, I'd assume a great portion of their customer base isn't offended by these types of URLs (as long as the .com backup is in place). As of now, a lot of people understand, and can find their way to these URLs, however there are still a considerable amount of users who are unfamiliar with any suffixes other then .com, .net, .edu and .org.

So, in the end I think it's really up to how you feel about your audience AND your potential audience.  Room for growth is always important and relying on such a unique URL could dilute the overall experience of a lot of users.

I'm not sure how this would effect the SEO of said site, but I would be very interested to see the analytics of these unique domains versus .com domains. Maybe on a large scale.

Comment: very good points; del.icio.us started out very much for the tech savvy. I actually note that their domain hack is now a redirect to delicious.com! Their branding has refocused on "delicious" not the domain hack (which must have happened since I last used the site).

Comment: @Ben Brocka: the change happened years ago! As a (tech savy) user I regret that change. The domain name was something that made it cool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is much of an issue, now that the URL bar in browsers starts to double as a search bar anyway. Typing the "cute" URL will result in a search page with the right site on it (probably right on top) anyway.

Comment: I don't think that this assumption should be made. This behavior is still far from universal, especially on non-desktop devices.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any good articles or data regarding this issue. 
it is probably worth noting that your example "del.icio.us" now goes to delicious.com .

A traditional domain will be preferable to a cute one.

You have very few chances to meet new users, you do not want any barriers to users visiting your site, such as having to figure out where a dot should be, or having to take scroll past some adverts to reach your results after a search.